# AngularJS Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Strangely enough the module loads perfectly in Firefox.

In Chrome only sometimes the module loads up (when refreshing on and off) and seems to be the only browser where the following console error is occurring.

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
var myApp =  angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyController($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://localhost/json").success(function(response){
        $scope.customers = response;
    });
});
myApp.controller('MyController', MyController);`
```

Comment: Are you using any minification/uglifying on the Javascript?

Comment: I am going to double check to make sure but I do believe I commented out/ disabled it in my gulp.js file.

Answer (score 0):

i think the ".success()" is avoiding the promise, you should use .then() instead, here is a link which explain it http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/

It works randomly because promises arent used in your case